# how to replace comma in List of string in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, expression

I have create one report with list of the string. The string got value parameter **TO.REFOS_STATUS_CODE  in ('10','ZZ','11','12','13')**. i want to  replace **","** with **"."**. i have try the solution with my expression but it does'nt work.
The parameter expression is **$P{refos_status}.equalsIgnoreCase("0") ?" ": " TO.REFOS_STATUS_CODE IN ( " +$P{refos_status}.replace( ',', '.' )+ ")"**.

Anyone know how to do that?

This is my query:

```
SELECT
TO.REFOS_STATUS_DESC_RPT ,
SUM(US.ENFUS_TOTAL_OFF_ACT) TOTAL
FROM TENF_RPT_UNSETTLE_SUMMACT US
INNER JOIN TREF_BRANCH B ON B.REFBR_BRANCH_ID = US.ENFUS_BRANCH
INNER JOIN TREF_STATE ST ON B.REFBR_STATE_CODE = ST.REFST_STATE_CODE
INNER JOIN TREF_OFFENCE_STATUS TO ON US.ENFUS_OFF_ACT =TO.REFOS_STATUS_CODE
WHERE
$P!{refos_status_1}

GROUP BY
TO.REFOS_STATUS_CODE,
TO.REFOS_STATUS_DESC_RPT
ORDER BY
TO.REFOS_STATUS_CODE,
TO.REFOS_STATUS_DESC_RPT
```

Comment: Maybe on the SQL side, one column expression with string concatenation `SELECT CONCAT(TO.REFOS_STATUS_DESC_RPT, '.', ...) FROM ...`?

Comment: my problem is the parameter. i want to replace the ',' into '.'.is there any solution?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle: `REPLACE(S, '.'. '-')` where S is the field.

Comment: i have already put the condition at above.Like this TO.REFOS_STATUS_CODE IN ( " +$P{refos_status}.replace( ',', '.' )+ ")" but the expression doesn't work. im using the DB2.

Comment: That was Java; in DB2 SQL REPLACE() also works.

Comment: BTW I gave no answer because `XXX in ('10'.'ZZ'.'11')` is no valid SQL. I do not understand the purpose. Maybe you should clarify a bit, for others too.